# Corresponding ID is not shown as "selected" result in dropdown

Tags: php, html, select, echo, selected

I've got a php page which will show a form. In the form you need to select a driver. Drivers are selected from a mysql db, that part works just fine. However, I would like to see that the user that is logged in, automatically is selected as default driver for this form.

What am I missing? Any help is greatly apprciated!

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');

$query  = "SELECT name, substring_index(substring_index(mrb_users.user_qualified,'|',-2),'|',1) as driver, id  ";
$query .= "from mrb_users having driver like 'B%' ORDER BY name ";
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value='". $row['id'] ."' if('".$row['id']."'==='".$_SESSION['id']."') 'selected'>" .$row['name'] . ' - ' .$row['chauffeur'] ."</option>" ;
}

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the PHP `if` statement is included in double quotes and therefore printed verbatim. If so, you should be able to see it using your browser's HTML inspector.

For clarity, I recommend (1) factoring out the `if` statement to a separate line and (2) using `sprintf()` instead of concatenating a large number of strings:

```php
$sel = ($row['id'] === $_SESSION['id'])
  ? 'selected'
  : '';
sprintf('<option value="%s" %s>%s - %s</option>',
        $row['id'], $sel, $row['name'], $row['chauffeur']);
```

Comment: Thanks, this for sure pointed me in the right direction. After reading your answer and looking in my browser inspection I noticed I was comparing two datatypes. And then I noticed the sprintf was not printed. My solutions is as below:
`$sel = ($row['id'] == $_SESSION['id'])
  ? 'selected'
  : '';
echo sprintf('<option value="%s" %s>%s - %s</option>',
        $row['id'], $sel, $row['name'], $row['chauffeur']);
}`